# Hide a field label

Tags: 7, theming, entities

Is there a way to hide the field label when rendering a custom field in Drupal 7?

In my node template I have:

```
<?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>
```

Which gives me:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-above">
  <div class="field-label">Image:&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">
      <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://site.com/sites/default/files/image.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to not have the `<div class="field-label">Image:&nbsp;</div>`.

Is there a way to get rid of this other than in the CSS or manually creating the markup?

I've tried `unset($content['field_image']['#title'])`, but that gives me `<div class="field-label">:&nbsp;</div>`.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, you set #label_display to hidden: 

`<?php $content['field_image']['#label_display'] = 'hidden'; ?>`

Comment: You could add that as an answer and accept it, so that it is clear the answer is resolved.

Comment: i had same issue but i want to do a field template for my node . how can i ? instead of removing the label

Comment: +1 on your question, Ben, but your *accepted* answer should be @Marta's answer below. NO need to write ANY CODE for this problem! Go to: admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR CONTENT TYPE/display to show your list of fields and under the Label, select <Hidden> from the drop down menu. Click the Save button. This answer should apply to field types, perhaps all of them, not just files.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the setting for field labels in the template you should instead use the setting under `Manage display` tab where you add and remove fields for your entity.

Comment: Googletorp, how do you hide the label of the title then?

Comment: If you edit the content type you can change the value in `Title field label`. It's a bit annoying that the title is still mandatory, but that's life I guess.

Comment: Is it possible to display the field labels differently when creating content and when displaying it publicly?

Comment: @Jay it would be possible, but would require code, either custom or through a module. I don't know of any module that does this for you right now though.

Comment: Ben, your accepted answer should be @Marta's answer below. No need to write any code! Go to: admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR CONTENT TYPE/display to show your list of fields and under the Label, select <Hidden> from the drop down menu. Click the Save button. This answer should apply to field types, perhaps all of them, not just files.

Answer (score 11):

To hide the name of a custom field (file field in this case with the name "file") in order to only show a list of downloadable files and not the name of the field do the following:

- Choose the Content Type that contains the file field (I created a new type called "File List")
- Navigate to the "Manage Fields" Tab
- Under Label choose "Hidden" and for Format, "Generic File"
- Save and create a new node of this content type and the name "file" should no longer be displayed

Comment: +1 @Marta's answer above should be the accepted answer - admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR CONTENT TYPE/display to show your list of fields and under the Label, select <Hidden> from the drop down menu. Click the Save button. This answer should apply to field types, perhaps all of them, not just files.

Comment: I agree! The less you do with coding or css in drupal the better :)

Answer (score 9):

```
$content['field_image']['#label_display']='hidden';
```

Comment: Best answer for my use case.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using the [#title_display](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#title_display) property of the Form API.

Comment: Is not that '#label_display'?

Answer (score 4):

using the template `field.tpl.php` you can remove or customize the label (`$label` in the template) of your field. to use it you must add the template field `field.tpl.php` to your theme:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```